# WPF ViewModel Changes Not Updating Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, data-binding

when a pressed to fetch data button , User_List in UserControllers is changed but listview in mainwindow is not updated.I use database as EntityFramework6.0
I share you UserController.cs(Viewmodel),Users.cs,MainWindow.cs,MainWindow.xaml
How can I fix this?

MainWindows.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window ,INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    ViewModels.UsersController controller1;

    public ObservableCollection<Users> user_List;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Users> User_List
    {
        get { return user_List; }
        set {lst1.ItemsSource=user_List = value;OnPropertyChanged("User_List"); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        controller1 = new ViewModels.UsersController();
        this.DataContext = controller1;
    }
   
   
    private void Fetch_Data_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModels.UsersController controller = new ViewModels.UsersController();
        controller.Increase();
        lst1.UpdateLayout();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
Window x:Class="MSSQLServer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MSSQLServer"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:MSSQLServer.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vw:UsersController/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button x:Name="Fetch_Data_Button" Click="Fetch_Data_Button_Click" Content="Fetch Data" Width="150" Height="40" FontSize="18" Margin="10,10"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListView x:Name="lst1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="300" Width="600" ItemsSource="{Binding User_List,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding surname,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding age,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="E-Mail" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120"></GridViewColumn>

                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
           

        </StackPanel>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserController.cs

```
public class UsersController :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Users> user_List;
        public ObservableCollection<Users> User_List
        {
            get { return user_List; }
            set { user_List = value;OnPropertyChanged("User_List"); }
        }
      
        public UsersController()
        {
            Increase();
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
       
       
        public void Increase()
        {
            Database1Entities entities = new Database1Entities();
            User_List = new ObservableCollection<Users>(entities.Users.ToList());
            
        }
    }
```

And Users.cs

```
public class Userss : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private int idd;
        public int id
        {
            get { return idd; }
            set { idd = value; OnPropertyChanged("id"); }
        }
        private string namee;
        public string name
        {
            get { return namee; }
            set { namee = value; OnPropertyChanged("name"); }
        }
        private string surnamee;
        public string surname
        {
            get { return surnamee; }
            set { surnamee = value; OnPropertyChanged("surname"); }
        }
        private int agee;
        public int age
        {
            get { return agee; }
            set { agee = value; OnPropertyChanged("age"); }
        }
        private string emaill;
        public string email
        {
            get { return emaill; }
            set { emaill = value; OnPropertyChanged("email"); }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you show your entity operation? And the database table design?

Comment: `Database1Entities entities = new Database1Entities();` Ccould you explain this code?

Comment: `controller1 = new ViewModels.UsersController();this.DataContext = controller1;`  `<Window.DataContext><vw:UsersController/></Window.DataContext>` Why is the data source set twice? Is there a conflict?

Comment: I tried binding from Mainwindow.cs And also Mainwindow.xaml

Comment: I created an object as entities to make crud operations

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my latest answer at: [C# wpf listview binding problem with observable collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778217/c-sharp-wpf-listview-binding-problem-with-observable-collection/69780982#69780982)

It's a basic example of how to work listviews/treeviews/gridviews at least at the beginning. If you try it then you will move most of your code into ViewModel part, but then you will search for commands and interaction between them (prism might be ok - i mean event aggregation, don't go Dependency Injection too fast).

One of your classes is named UsersController. When you switch to WPF, remember that MVC pattern is no longer alive and most of it is somewhere in ViewModel, so it's more like UserViewModel or UsersViewModel. If I read you correctly then I'm telling you that it's hard to switch from classic MVC (various implementations) to some sort of correct, pleasant MVVM.

The URL I provided has one major thing missing which is the standard ViewModelWrapper, usually called ViewModelBase or BaseViewModel, call it yourself.

It takes shape of (it should be the part of my first post though):

```
namespace MyNamespace.ViewModel
{
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get rid of the following XAML since you are setting the `DataContext` programmatically:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vw:UsersController/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Second, you should call the `Increase()` method of the data-bound instance of the `UsersController`:

```
private void Fetch_Data_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    controller1.Increase();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is another way to do it in BaseViewModel:

```cs
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T fieldReference, T newValue, Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    bool valueIsDifferent = false;
    if (!object.Equals(fieldReference, newValue))
    {
        valueIsDifferent = true;
        fieldReference = newValue;

        var memberExpression = property.Body as MemberExpression;
        OnPropertyChanged(memberExpression.Member.Name);
    }
    return valueIsDifferent;
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

here is how to use it in your view model

```
    private int _myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _myProperty, value, () => MyProperty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).